# little confusion click on li element instead of href tags

Tags: jquery, html

html:

```
    <ul class="navTabs">
        <li class="navActive"><a href="#one">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#fourth">fourth</a></li>
        <li><a href="#fifth">fifth</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="navContent">
        <div id="one">
            one
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            two
        </div>
        <div id="three">
            three
        </div>
        <div id="fourth">
            fourth
        </div>
        <div id="fifth">
            fifth
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have this code which runs when i click on the `<a></a>` tag.

```
jQuery('.navTabs > li > a').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery(this.hash).show().siblings().hide();
}).filter(':first').click();
```

But i want to apply the above code for the clicking on the `li` element. this is what i am trying but its not working.

```
jQuery('.navTabs > li').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href').show().siblings().hide();
}
```

I also tried this: `jQuery(this).find('a').href.show().siblings().hide();` but that didn't work either.

Comment: try `$('.navTabs li').on('click', 'a', function(e) {...});`

Comment: i want to click on the li element but want to show current li href to show.

Comment: then try `$('.navTabs').on('click', 'li', function(e) { ... });` show your html or better create jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery('.navTabs > li').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var theHref = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
    jQuery(theHref).show().siblings().hide();
}
```